# mlx5_core 0000:b5:00.0: mlx5_cmd_check:772:(pid 5271): CREATE_SQ(0x904) op_mod(0x0) failed, status bad parameter(0x3), syndrome (0xd61c0b)

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, nic, mellanox

I am facing following issue when creating pod using sriov network.
when i see output of device driver using

```
$**dmesg** 
*mlx5_core 0000:b5:00.0: mlx5_cmd_check:772:(pid 5271): CREATE_SQ(0x904) op_mod(0x0) failed, status bad parameter(0x3), syndrome (0xd61c0b)*
```

seems some issue in communication with hardware. below listed system details:

```
PCI:  b5:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT28841
Driver: mlx5_core (5.0-0.0)
Card: ConnectX-6 Dx
OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-89-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

**below are the network yaml:**
[image]

**pod yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mellonox-test-pod
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: sriov-rdma-net1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mellonox-alpine
    image: alpine
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 300000; done;" ]
    resources:
      requests:
        mellanox.com/mlnx_sriov_rdma: '1'
      limits:
        mellanox.com/mlnx_sriov_rdma: '1'
```

**pod creation result:**

```
$kubectl describe pod mellonox-test-pod
`"error bringing interface up in container ns: \"invalid argument\""`
```

After that when i see device driver output, got this issue `*mlx5_core 0000:b5:00.0: mlx5_cmd_check:772:(pid 5271): CREATE_SQ(0x904) op_mod(0x0) failed, status bad parameter(0x3), syndrome (0xd61c0b)*.`

Would be great to receive any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you maybe try to be more specific in the network annotations? seems something related to the namespace, add metadata.namespace=target_namespace.

Be aware the target_namespace needs to be the same in both the Pod spec and the SriovNetowrk CR.

Cheers.